# When I enter input in Edittext and When I Select Spinner item.After both will be non change or Non editable

Tags: android, xml

I have one spinner contain 4 items and 4 edittext. I entered input in editText and select also drop down item.
Once i clicked `Button` (`onlick`) then all editText and Spinner item  should be no change.

I already use this but it not work.

```
Edittext.setEnabled(true);
 Edittext.requestFocus();
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: Please make it more clear :)

Comment: use setEnabled(false);

Comment: @Thanks Amiya .Code is not work properly..

Comment: what about spinner sir ?

Comment: Ok i Will try then let u know sir.

Comment: Ok, and cut the "sir" word :D

Comment: @berserk I checked it out. its not working brother....any diff solution ??

Comment: O.o spinner not disabled?

Comment: yeah only i check with edittext ..   my three edittext is there...                                                   groupno.setEnabled(false);
        start.setEnabled(false);
        end.setEnabled(false);

Comment: You want to make the spinner disable right?

Comment: yes.i want to make spinner disable mode

Comment: Well spinner.setEnabled(false) is working for me

Comment: @berserk  thanks its working :) please write that 1 line code in answer...after this mark as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
edittext.setEnabled(false);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```